# Check all domains served by a DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

Is there any way to query a dns server to find out all the domains it is the authoritative server? [all domains it has configured?]

(I can use dig or any other tool)

Comment: It depends, bind views or ACLS could very possibly exclude you from seeing some of the domains the server is responsible for.

Comment: You might try an axfr if it's allowed.

Comment: Roman, how will that help?  Do you plan to try AXFRs of every registered domain, and see which ones it responds with?

Comment: Aww. Been thinking about my current setup where I control the DNS server.

Comment: All of the above comments suggesting ways are *wrong*.  You need to get ahold of the DNS server configuration to determine this, so the answer is simply **no** in any practical sense.  Contact the server administrator and ask for it, care of DNS services, 2204 Fat Chance Ave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to query a dns server to find out all the domains it
>   is the authoritative server?

Short of doing millions and millions of queries in a brute-force style,  no there is no way to do this.

*If* you know one of the domains, and *if* they have enabled `axfr` for your IP, you can get a list of records for a single domain.